# How does the const a = express() works exactly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I recently started learning Node/express. One doubt is bugging me for a couple of weeks now. I know what this does, and I've been able to get past it. But I cannot wrap my head around the logic used in the line `const a = express()`.

```
express = require('express');
const a = express()
```

I don't think I have seen this before in javascript. In this case, `express` is an object or function (functions are also object in JavaScript) right? And this line is what gives the variable `a` access to lots of important methods like `listen()` and `get()`. But doesn't the syntax here is wrong? To use the `express()` function, we need to write like

```
const express = require('express');
const a = express.express()
```

or we need to use object destructuring to write like

```
const {express} = require('express');
const a = express()
```

Comment: Because `require('express')` returns something *callable*…?!

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html — *"The `express()` function is a top-level function exported by the `express` module."*

Comment: `But I cannot wrap my head around the logic used in the line 'const a = express()'`: just see `express()` as a function that returns a function, everything will make sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the confusion is in assuming that the default export of the `express` module is something other than a function, but as others have pointed out, the [default export](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html) of `express` *is* a function. Once imported, the returned value of that function is an instance of Express which is where you then have access to all those methods you mentioned.

Imagine that the definition of `function express` and the object it returns  looks something like

```js
class Express {
 // Implementation of Express server 
}
// You're importing this and calling the function, receiving a new instance of this class. In reality this could be a class or object for all I know. 
export default function express() {
  return new Express() 
}
```